# processor architecture for debian

Tags: debian, cpu

What is the architecture of this processor http://ark.intel.com/products/49490 ? In other words what version of Debian should I install? http://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst#verysmall

Comment: This should be on SuperUser.

Comment: Install AMD64..

Answer (score 1):

The table lists "Instruction Set 64-bit", so install `amd64`. (Yes, it's an Intel, but Debian calls the Intel x86-64 `amd64` because AMD invented the 64-bit extensions.)

Answer (score 0):

That processor, since it's AMD's 64 bits architecture, you have to install amd64 version.

Comment: Technically, it's Intel's 64bit architecture. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amd64#Differences_between_AMD64_and_Intel_64

Comment: Technically, it's not. Intel's 64-bit architecture is IA64, not AMD64. Quoting your link: "x86-64 [...] The original specification was created by AMD, and has been implemented by AMD, Intel, VIA, and others". Look at larsmans answer as well.

Comment: There's a difference between IA64 and Intel64.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article that i've linked and tell me how they are the **same**

Comment: x86-64 was introduced by AMD. Intel later adapted this to his own. Same happened with IA32 adapted by AMD, and you don't call it AMD architecture, do you? And I know they're the same, buy x86-64 was introduced by AMD. Like it or not. I'm not discussing this obviousness any further.

Answer (score 0):

Either one one of the x86 derivatives without kfreebsd - the 32 bit i386 or the 64 bit AMD64 (intel uses a compatible architecture called EMT64, but since AMD was first to market, many refer to it as AMD64 - the correct generic name is x86-64) would do, practically speaking - the 64 bit x86 architecture is backward compatible with the 32 bit architecture. This would install the good, stable well tested linux kernel

The kfreebsd alternatives use a freebsd kernel with debian userland tools. Its shiny if you want to play with BSD things in a familiar environment but *not* what you're looking for. ia64 (aka itanium), S390 (a mainframe platform) and power PC simply won't run, since they are fundamentally different architectures.

That being said, if you have, or want to max out the memory, you *have* to go for the 64 bit architecture (there's workarounds but don't bother). If you have i386 specific applications, you *should* be covered using the compatibility libraries, you should probably need some form of ia-32-libs package to run it on 64 bit.

All that taken into account, AMD64 bit is the better option